# ¿Por qué al crear una arista entre 2 vértices la conexión se realiza a todos los vértices?

Tags: python, estructuras-de-datos, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo el siguiente código de una representación de un grafo en python mi problema radica en que al enlazar una arista a un vertice la conexión se aplica a todos los vertices creados y no solo a la conexión que quiero crear. En el ejemplo el resultado esperado debería ser:
**vertice1 : 2
, vertice2 :
, vertice3 :**

Pero imprime: **vertice1: 2, vertice2: 2, vertice3: 2**

```
class Vertex:
  edges = []

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
  
  def find_edge(self, vertex):
    for edge in self.edges:
      if (vertex.value == edge.value):
        return True
    return False

  def add_edge(self, edge):
    if (self.find_edge(edge) == False):
      self.edges.append(Vertex(edge.value))
```

```
from vertex import Vertex

class Graph:
  vertexes = []

  def add_vertex(self, value):
    self.vertexes.append(Vertex(value))

  def search_vertex(self, value):
    for vertex in self.vertexes:
      if (vertex.value == value):
        return vertex
    return None

  def link_edges(self, origin, destination):
    if (origin != None and destination != None):
      origin.add_edge(destination)

  def print_matrix(self):
    for vertex in self.vertexes:
      print("vertice:" + str(vertex.value) + ": ", end = "")
      for edge in vertex.edges:
        print(edge.value, end = " ")
      print("")
```

```
from graph import Graph

def main():
  graph = Graph()

  graph.add_vertex(1)
  graph.add_vertex(2)
  graph.add_vertex(3)

  graph.link_edges(graph.search_vertex(1), graph.search_vertex(2))

  graph.print_matrix()
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en la confusión entre variables de clase y variables de instancia.

Esto es una variable de clase:

```
class Vertex:
  edges = []
```

La variable `edges` es compartida por **todos** los objectos de la clase `Vertex`.

La alternativa es una variable de instancia. Si quieres que cada objeto `Vertex` tenga su propia lista `edges`, tienes que inicializarlo usando `self.edges`, asi:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.edges = []
```

Por rigor, también deberías aplicar lo mismo en la clase `Graph`:

```
class Graph:
  def __init__(self):
      self.vertexes = []
```

produce:

```
vertice:1: 2 
vertice:2: 
vertice:3:
```